# Non-degenerate stochastic process

Tags: stochastic-processes

I am writing my thesis on the ACD model of Engle and Russel (1998). Because of the great similarities with GARCH, a common feature is non-degeneracy or non-degeneration. Apparently it is absolute basic knowledge, because I can figure out what non-degeneracy is. The ACD or GARCH process are basically stochastic processes. I would like to know what non-degeneration in context of a stochastic process is.

Comment: It depends on the context.  You'll have to look at the source where you saw the term used - maybe they give a definition, or maybe the meaning can be inferred from context.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it would be better asked on cross validated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A nondegenerate stochastic process has a nonzero variance, or equivalently, a nonzero diffusion coefficient.